# I moved Xcode into the Applications folder and now I am unable to use it

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard

Please brace with me, as I am a beginner and it may be difficult to follow along. Thank you for reading though!

I use an older MacBook Pro from a few years ago, a MacOSX 10.6.8, and I use Xcode 3, because Xcode 4 is incompatible. (I plan to upgrade to Mac OSX Lion this weekend.)

So anyway, I wanted to move Xcode into the Applications folder so that I could directly access Xcode straight from the Applications folder. Sorry, but I forgot which directory Xcode was in before I moved it to Applications. :/

```
Process:         Xcode [4055]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
Version:         ??? (???)
Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-18070000~38
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [125]

Date/Time:       2013-05-24 23:21:11.523 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          6224045 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           6617
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5
Anonymous UUID:                      C57BF95A-98BC-4214-87DF-30BC2B423297

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/DevToolsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsFoundation
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3be0f  dyld 132.1 (???) <29DECB19-0193-2575-D838- CF743F0400B2> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro5,3, BootROM MBP53.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 g, 4 GB, SMC 1.48f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02, 298.09 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0x26500000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0304, 0x06200000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8213, 0x06110000 / 4
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0236, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
```

I didn't know what part was wrong, so I included the whole error, sorry. :/

I don't understand what "Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded:" means. Can somebody please help me use Xcode 3 again?

I'm upgrading to OSX Lion, but I'm desperate to get coding because my fingers itch to get working on that rogue-like I was working on :3

Thank you very much for reading! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error message in the post broke. Sorry :/

Comment: Xcode 3 is installed in /Developper/Applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of Xcode are not supposed to be moved. You'll have to re-install Xcode 3, or move the files back to their original location in /Developer (if you remember).

If your computer has sufficient Specs, I highly recommend running Xcode 4 and Lion - it will be easier to find information and support.

Comment: Upgrade to 4 or reinstall 3